# what cross entropy or neg-loglikelihood is sufficient to can stop training?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I train a neural network using cost function as cross-entropy or neg-loglikelihood function. At what function value can I think it is time to stop training and the result is good?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically when you get to zero. Practically, you never get to zero of course. In some occasions, the network classification performance is close to 100% while the crossentropy is far from zero (because the probability is almost uniformly distributed among all choices and it is only slightly higher for the correct class). According to my personal experience, the crossentropy value may even start to increase while your accuracy still improves. So no value is your answer.

PS: The underlying reason is crossentropy is a convex approximate for the underlying non-convex 0/1 loss function. These two may behave differently as you get closer to a local minima point.